# iOS UIScrollView and Autolayout not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout

As already mentioned in the title, i got a little problem with a ScrollView and Autolayout in my Storyboad.

I have already made a view with an UIScrollView and it works as expected. But I am struggling since weeks with a different view.

I remade the view several times but I dont know what im doing wrong.

The problem is that I can only scroll horizontally and not vertically as usual.
I have also tried copying the old view and changing the content but that hasnt worked either.

The most strange thing, is that the preview of the view looks different as it does in the simulator or on my phone.

Here are a few Screenshots:

### Storyboard:

(left: document outline | middle: storyboard | right: preview)

[*CLICK*](http://i.gyazo.com/1972a52ad9a62beebd097877dfa6a3f1.png)

### Simulator:

(As you can see i can only scroll horizontally)

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help (:

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect the elements in the ScrollView with constraints vertically, so the ScrollView knows how wide it's inside is.

Comment: Yes, make sure the label has a width constraint, otherwise it will shrink.

Comment: But if i add a width constraint, it doesnt fit on different screen sizes.
Or am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: Oh yeah, so make it so it fits on the larger devices, on the smaller devices it will be scrollable anyways.

Comment: I actually did. You can see the constraints on the left and right where i set the label width.